# How do I remove password?

Tags: password

How do I remove password so at startup I do not have to enter a password.  I am running Ubuntu 12.04.
I have tried searching answers.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **System Settings**.  Then to **User Accounts**. Now you should see **Login Automatically** flip it on.  If it is grey, click **Unlock** at the top then enter **root password**.

Comment: Just be aware that this is only suitable for a single-user setup, or in a scenario where one particular user uses the computer most of the time... If you have multiple users, this may not be ideal.

Comment: This does not remove the password, anything that requires sudo still asks for a password